# Multiple entities in one UITableview

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uitableview

I have a data model with two entitys with relationship one to many. Lets call them City<-->>Person.

In my tableview Im currently displaying each City, seperated by sections (currently one cell in each section).

Is there any way for me to add each Person connected to the specific city in the corresponding section? (adding as many cells as number of persons connected to the city)

Im using two different fetchedResultsControllers to access the Entities but cant quite figure out how to do this. 
Ultimately Id like each sections first cell to be a city, followed by all the persons in that city.

Any help or pointer in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have to display each City in a cell? Maybe showing Cities as section titles would be enough. This way you will have to deal only with one fetchedResultsController (for Person entity), which will simplify things a lot.

Comment: I do need to be able to display detailviews for all cells, both citys and persons. However if this way is easier maybe I could modify the sectionheaders to look like cells and still be able to show a citys detailview that way.

Comment: you think that would be a better solution? @MichałCiuba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michal mentioned in comments.  A cleaner design would be for your City entities to be displayed in the section headers (pretty easy) and have your person objects in the sections as rows.

To do that you need to add a unique identifier from the city as your section path of your `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Since that attribute takes a key path you can specify something like `city.name` and it will resolve through the relationship from person to city and get that value.

Your only other option would be to manually fetch the city objects and build your `UITableViewDatasource` to talk to your own construct of data.  Doable but far, far more difficult than what Michal suggested.

Comment: The problem now is that if I just add a City, the NSFetchedResultsController wont find and add it to the tableview (as a sectionheader) since there is no relationships set up yet. I need to be able to display Citys only until user adds persons. Is there any way to check for this without using a second fethedresultscontroller ?

Comment: Not easily.  Tables aren't meant to have a section with no rows. You can work around it but that is unpleasant.

Comment: so a second fetchedresultscontroller is the way to go ?

Comment: No, the UX is flawed. You should not be doing that it violates the HIG. I recommend finding another design.